# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: This object has not been built" when adding custom filter

Tags: spring, spring-security

I added custom filter before BasicAuth

```
<sec:custom-filter ref="authorizationFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
```

Filter works, implements Filter as well, but i get that exception at `AbstractSecurityBuilder.getObject()`.

Why it just can't filter the request without calling all that "spring-zoo"?

Answer (score 0):

Did your authorizationFilter registered as Spring bean?